# What is the difference between nulltypes :: and 0n in KDB?

Tags: kdb

Both of these appear to be null types, but seem to behave differently.

For example, if instantiate a dictionary with

```
`a`b!(0n 0n)
```

I'm unable to upsert integers, where as I can if i do:

```
`a`b!(:: ::)
```

I can. What is the difference between `0n` and `::`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

0N actually defaults to 0Nj. Same way if you define non-float numbers they will also be long. 0N is not equivalent to :: because of this.

If you want the values of your dictionary to be integers, you would need to define it as such:  `` `a`b!0N 0Ni `` (or keep it as generic null with the identity)

Comment: Does :: have a data type? Or is it a type of it's own? It seems to behave as a function x = ::[x]

Comment: A quick check of this as `type[::]` gives `101h`, `unary primitive`. I guess it's special!

Comment: Deleted my initial comment as quickly realised was wrong.  `::` Has many use cases so does classify as a primitive. But it is also considered to be untyped / equivalent to 0 but not actually a list. This forces a list or key/values to be untyped. Just typing 0N does not achieve the same due to the default typing